# How to implement restful API with additional noun for entity

Tags: rest, sails.js

I would like to implement the following restful API using sails js:
(https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/11/a-restful-learning-curve-nouns-verbs-hateoas-and-roca/)

```
…/customers/[customer_id]/approval
```

I will PUT method to send approval information, and GET method to get the approval status.

It is quite easy in Sails js to implement in the following way:

```
…/customers/approval/[customer_id]
```

I only need to add a method `approval` in CustomerController.js. But if I want to implement the first approach (i.e. `[customer_id]` followed by `approval`. How can I do that in Sails js?

By the way, which API style is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write your own route

`/customers/:customer_id/approval : 'CustomerController.approval'`

Then inside your controller/action you would have access to `req.param.customer_id`

Checkout these links

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes